Source for quote saying "why don't you want to die" or "why do you want to live forever"
I recently read a quote saying "why don't you want to die" or "why do you want to live forever". It must be an old book (antiquity). The author asked this to someone. I don't remember if he gets an answer or not, but it goes on about the fear of death. I thought it could have been Seneca's "De Vita Beata" but I couldn't find it.
